# Django: Querying Database

Tags: python, django

Here's my model,

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    ....
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='answer_likes')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

I wants to filter out the Answers which received maximum likes in last 24 hours.

I got this solution,

```
timing = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)
data = Answer.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=timing).annotate(final=Count('likes')).order_by('-final')
```

But this is not what I want. I wants to filter out the answers which received the maximum likes in last 24 hour in the entire database not the ones asked in last 24 hours & received maximum likes. How can i do that?

Thank You :)

Comment: It looks like you're not saving the creation time of individual likes, so you don't have enough information to do what you're asking. I suggest adding a new Like model with a created_time timestamp field.

Comment: Are you tracking how many likes an answer gets in 24 hours? I think this is a good use case for caching. [See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#basic-usage). I don't recommend saving "like" time in the db, that's just inefficient and redundant.